# How do I extract the function from an underscore .forEach call?

Tags: underscore.js

Normally I'd write a .forEach like this:

```
_.forEach(results, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

If I want to extract that method, I could do:

```
  logIt: function(result){
    console.log(result);
}

_.forEach(results, logIt);
```

Is there a way to extract the function and still pass in a parameter? For example, if my function was something like this:

```
_.forEach(results, function(result){
   if(log){
       console.log(result);
   }
});
```

How could I pass both result and the log variable into a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`_.bind`](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) for partial application:

> **bind** `_.bind(function, object, [*arguments])`
>
> Bind a **function** to an **object**, meaning that whenever the function is called, the value of this will be the **object**. Optionally, pass **arguments** to the function to pre-fill them, also known as **partial application**.

So you can say things like this:

```
f = function(x, y) { ... };
g = _(f).bind(null, 11);
```

to make `g(6)` behave the same as saying `f(11, 6)`.

So if you had this:

```
var obj = {
    logIt: function(log, result) {
        if(log)
            console.log(result);
    }
};
```

then you could say:

```
_.forEach(result, _.bind(obj.logIt, null, whatever_log_should_be));
```

to pass `whatever_log_should_be` as the `log` parameter during the iteration. If you need a specific `this` inside `logIt` then use that value instead of `null`:

```
_.bind(obj.logIt, obj, ...)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zBvuJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
function logIt2(log){

    return function(result){
        if(log){
           console.log(result);
        }
    }
}

_.forEach( results, logIt2(logger) );
```